# Как вывести все последовательности переменных?

Tags: python, алгоритм

```
x = 2
y = 4
z = 12

print(x, y, z)
print(x, z, y)
print(y, x, z)
print(y, z, x)
print(z, x, y)
print(z, y, x)
```

Как автоматизировать этот процесc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import itertools

x, y, z = 2, 4, 12

for num in itertools.permutations([x, y, z]):
    print(num)
```